# Why am I unable to move "Card" to the center of screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a quite weird problem (and a few of my fellows) that we are unable to put "card" bootstrap class to screen center, we tried a lot of solutions which were available on the internet, but neither of those worked out.

Here's the div that doesn't want to move:

```
<div class="container h-100">
        <div class="flex-center-wrap">
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
        <h5 class="card-title mb-2">hihihihihih</h5>
        <div class="card-subtitle mb-3">hihihihi<a href="#" target="_blank">hihihihi</a></div>
        <form id="generateSignatureForm" method="post" action="/?/api/generateSignature">
        <input id="generateSignatureUsername" class="form-control form-control-sm mb-3" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" required="">
        <input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="46d2ce8a-2271-471f-a46f-c58234324e99">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is a quick showup of how it looks like (that div is overlapping a navbar and doesn't want to go to center), vizualization is [Here](https://codepen.io/Zeczero/pen/wvagrZG)

Comment: Also, some typos in codepen like `justify-cointent-center` should be `justify-content-center`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use `align-items`, which is a flex item property, on a div that's not a flex item.

Also, you are trying to align on the screen, but your `html` and `body` don't have `height: 100%` set.

To demonstrate, you can add `style="height: 100vh; display: flex;"` to the parent `div`. As you can see below, the card is getting correctly centered.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,700');











/*---Media Queries --*/
@media (max-width: 992px) {

  }
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  
}
@media (max-width: 576px) {
  
}

a {
  color: #d7eaf4;
}



body {
  color: #fff;
  background: #2834d8 url(img/hotel.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: poppins,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

/*---Firefox Bug Fix --*/
.carousel-item {
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}
/*--- Fixed Background Image --*/
figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 0!important;
}

.footer {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 1rem!important;
}

.fixed-wrap {
  clip: rect(0, auto, auto, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100%!important;
}


.navbar {
  background: rgba(18,13,33,.8);
  color: #d7eaf4;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px #000000c0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#fixed {
  background-image: url('img/mac.png');
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
          transform: translateZ(0);
  will-change: transform;
}
/*--- Bootstrap Padding Fix --*/
[class*="col-"] {
    padding: 1rem;
}

.card {
  margin: 0 auto; /* Added */
  float: none; /* Added */
  margin-bottom: 10px; /* Added */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#0e1a33" />
 <title>Hotel Morenka Cipa</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
 <link href="theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
  data-target="#navbarResponsive">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>

 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
   <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Ranking</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Support</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
 <footer class="footer fixed-bottom">
  Copyright © 2020 Kuba Wroński & Mateusz Gołębiowski
 </footer>

 <div class=" d-dlex  justify-content-center align-items-center a div" style="height: 100vh; display: flex;">
  <div class="d-dlex  justify-content-center align-items-center a div">
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
     <h5 class="card-title mb-2">hihihihihih</h5>
      <div class="card-subtitle mb-3">hihihihi<a href="#" target="_blank">hihihihi</a></div>
  <form id="generateSignatureForm" method="post" action="/?/api/generateSignature">
  <input id="generateSignatureUsername" class="form-control form-control-sm mb-3" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" required="">
  <input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="46d2ce8a-2271-471f-a46f-c58234324e99">
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add css class

```css
.centered {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#0e1a33" />
 <title>Hotel Morenka Cipa</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
 <link href="theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
  data-target="#navbarResponsive">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>

 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
   <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Ranking</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Support</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
 <footer class="footer fixed-bottom">
  Copyright © 2020 Kuba Wroński & Mateusz Gołębiowski
 </footer> 
///////////////////// add class here
<div class="centered">
 <div class=" d-dlex  justify-cointent-center align-items-center a div">
  <div class="d-dlex  justify-cointent-center align-items-center a div">
      <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
     <h5 class="card-title mb-2">hihihihihih</h5>
      <div class="card-subtitle mb-3">hihihihi<a href="#" target="_blank">hihihihi</a></div>
  <form id="generateSignatureForm" method="post" action="/?/api/generateSignature">
  <input id="generateSignatureUsername" class="form-control form-control-sm mb-3" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" required="">
  <input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="46d2ce8a-2271-471f-a46f-c58234324e99">
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```